# How can I rewrite this to give me a list of answers?

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming, any help would be much appreciated! I am having trouble with a piece of coding I am writing in Python. My task is to write a function to calculate the number of times a particular letter appears divided by the total number of letters in that sequence.
My function is supposed to return a list with the fraction of letters for each sequence.

```
def calculate_let(sequences, letter):
    calculate_letNew = []
    for seq in sequences:
        len(seq)
        calculate_letNew = seq.count(letter)/len(seq)
    return calculate_letNew
```

This is my code so far. The output gives me a fraction for only **one** sequence even tough the list `sequenceA` has four sequences.

```
Letter_A = calculate_let(sequenceA, 'A')
print(Letter_A)
```

output: `0.10273972602739725`

I have been trying my hardest to try and solve this problem, but quite honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Badly indented Python is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to make a list of them like this:

Notice the `list.append` method will add an element to the list.

```
def count_lett(sequences, AminoAcid):
    count_lettNew = []
    for seq in sequences:
        count_lettNew.append(seq.count(AminoAcid)/len(seq))
    return count_lettNew
```

---

As random advice:

Python only uses the TitleCase for class names, so I would choose to write the code like this (keeping the `forloop` for simplicity):

```
def count_lett(sequences, amino_acid):
    counts = [] # Although, you may consider something like fracs 
                # for "fractions" since these aren't actually counts
    for seq in sequences:
        counts.append(seq.count(amino_acid)/len(seq))
    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a very readable and concise way using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def calc_freqs(sequences, letter):
    return [seq.count(letter)/len(seq) for seq in sequences]

sequenceA = 'ALABAMA', 'MISSISSIPPI', 'UTAH', 'IDAHO'
letterA = calc_freqs(sequenceA, 'A')
print(letterA)  # -> [0.5714285714285714, 0.0, 0.25, 0.2]
```